# UK Covid Pass "expires" during holiday in Spain

Tags: covid-19, spain, vaccinations

I have my travel COVID pass, which I will use on entry to Spain to prove Ive been vaccinated and boosted. However the "Valid Until" Expires during my stay. Does any one know if this is a problem?
I have checked here: https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/spain/entry-requirements#entry-rules-in-response-to-coronavirus-covid-19
But it does not mention anything about proof expiring, except for limitations on how much time has passed since vaccination/booster shots.

Answer (score 22):

A bit more digging later:
https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/coronavirus-covid-19/get-digital-covid-pass/

> How long a digital NHS COVID Pass is valid for
> A digital NHS COVID Pass is valid for 30 days. The 30-day period refreshes and starts again each time you log in.

> If you have an NHS COVID Pass for travel based on a positive PCR test, the 30-day period will refresh for up to 180 days after you took the test.

> If you use the NHS App for your NHS COVID Pass, it may ask you to confirm your phone number when you log in. If you do not confirm it, your NHS COVID Pass will be valid for only 72 hours.

> If you download your digital NHS COVID Pass as a PDF it will be valid for 30 days. Always check the expiry date before using it.

So curiously, the act of signing into the NHS app, makes the vaccine and booster work a little longer! ;-)

Comment: Not just signing into the NHS app. Signing into the NHS app *with internet connectivity* (it can't refresh without it). If you might not have internet while abroad, then simply load the NHS app shortly before you leave on holiday. If you are on holiday for more than 30 days, you will need to find some internet connectivity on holiday.

Comment: (+1) It's the same logic than a driving license: It makes it possible to revoke them, add security features, etc. but the original basis for it (e.g. the driving test or training you had to take) remains valid, only the document gets updated. Note that in the EU at least, the logic is in the reading app, you can have a “valid” pass that's not accepted for some purpose in some country. In spite of the Commission's best effort, each country has slightly different rules regarding the length of time after vaccination, testing, etc. (don't know how it interacts with the UK system).

Comment: This sort of arrangement is very common where some form of credential is issued and then accepted without requiring a connection back to the issuer to ensure it is still valid. This is very common in web and application security as otherwise someone with a copy of the token would be able to claim to be the user or to have the same rights as when the token was originally issued, no matter how many times the user claims their password or the rights change. In this case it is likely to allow the definition of "fully vaccinated" to change, as has already happened with the introduction of boosters.

Comment: Interesting about the 180 day line. I’m triple jabbed (Pfizer, Pfizer, Moderna) and I had a positive test October, but my pass is still only 30 days. I guess it prioritises the vaccines. Also, this doesn’t apply here because 30 days is too long, but if you test positive your pass really shouldn’t stay valid (for the isolation period)!

Comment: @Tim It's a 180-day pass, but you only get given it in 30-day increments.

Answer (score 5):

It may seem strange that you can update your pass by the simple act of logging in and requesting a new one. But I think the motivation is that the pass should be available from your phone, whether or not you have access to the internet at the time that you need it. So it is valid for thirty days, after which you must check in with Covid Central to keep your status up to date.